# Emulate C# lock statement in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

**Intro**: For synchronization, C# offers the `System.Threading.Monitor`class, offering thread synchronization routines such as `Enter()`, `Exit()`, `TryEnter()` and alike.

Furthermore, there is the `lock` statement that makes sure a lock gets destroyed when a critical code block is left, either by normal execution flow or by an exception:

```
private static readonly obj = new Object();

lock(obj) {
   ...
}
```

**Problem:** In C++, for this purpose, we got the RAII wrappers `std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock` that are not applied to `Monitor` classes but to types fulfilling the `Lockable` concept. However, I consider this approach syntactically weaker than the way C# implemented it for several reasons:

You pollute the local scope with a variable name that cannot be reused. This can be countered by adding new scopes like

```
  {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck{ mtx };
      ...
  }
```

But I find this notation rather awkward-looking. What troubles me even more that this is valid C++:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex>{ mtx ]; // note there is no name to the lock!
...
```

So by forgetting to give a proper name to the lock guard, this statement will be interpreted as a variable declaration named "mtx" of type `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`, without having anything locked!

I want to implement something like the `lock` statement from C# in C++. In C++17, this can be accomplished very easily:

```
#define LOCK(mutex) if(std::lock_guard<decltype(mutex)> My_Lock_{ mutex }; true)

std::mutex mtx;
LOCK(mtx) {
   ...
}
```

**Q: How can I implement this in C++11/14?**

Comment: Off-topic, but word to the wise: Those identifiers (containing the double underscores) [are reserved to the implementation for any use](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3).

Comment: @StoryTeller A'ight, I just want to make sure the name is obscure enough it never collides with anything.

Comment: You should probably just get used to C# and C++ being totally different languages, and not try to fight the language. I think that `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ mtx };` is very "natural" but that `private static readonly obj = new Object();` looks extremely complicated. Why don't you need a macro for that? :-)

Comment: @BoPersson This is just a variable initialization, it can look very differently in different occassions. While being two different languages, I think there is nothing wrong in trying to adopt things that work very well in one language in another one.

Comment: It depends on how much you bend the language to make it look familiar. People coming from Pascal might try `#define begin {` and `#define end }` to feel more at home, but soon have to give up on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by StoryTeller's great idea, I think I found a viable solution myself, despite being somewhat a "hack":

```
template <typename T>
struct Weird_lock final : private std::lock_guard<T> {
    bool flip;
    Weird_lock(T& m) : std::lock_guard<T>{ m }, flip{ true } { }

    operator bool() noexcept {
        bool old = flip;
        flip = false;
        return old;
    }
};

#define LOCK(mutex) for(Weird_lock<decltype(mutex)> W__l__{ mutex }; W__l__;)
```

The good thing is that it doesn't need a semicolon in the end. The bad is the need for an additional `bool`, but from what I see in godbolt.org, the compiler optimizes this out anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Putting aside the "should you do this", here's how:

While it's not quite the same, since it requires a semi-colon, it's near enough that I feel I may present it. This pure C++14 solution basically just defines the macro to start a lambda which is immediately executed:

```
template<typename MTX>
struct my_lock_holder {
    MTX& mtx;
    my_lock_holder(MTX& m) : mtx{m} {}
};

template<typename MTX, typename F>
void operator+(my_lock_holder<MTX>&& h, F&& f) {
    std::lock_guard<MTX> guard{h.mtx};
    std::forward<F>(f)();
}

#define LOCK(mtx) my_lock_holder<decltype(mtx)>{mtx} + [&]
```

The `my_lock_holder` just nabs the mutex reference for later, and allows us to overload `operator+`. The idea is that the operator creates the guard and execute the lambda. As you can see the macro defines a default reference capture, so that lambda will be able to reference anything in the enclosing scope. Then it's pretty much straight forward:

```
std::mutex mtx;
LOCK(mtx) {

}; // Note the semi-colon
```

And you can see it build <kbd>[live](https://ideone.com/cE1nKM)</kbd>.

Comment: This is definitely useful and quite clever, therefore the upvote. Can something like that be also done with C++11?

Comment: @Jodocus - You know, I don't think I used any C++14 specific features. I just didn't try it in C++11 mode. It may very well work as is.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do:

```
#define UNIQUE_NAME(name) name##__COUNTER__
#define LOCK(mutex) std::lock_guard<decltype(mutex)> UNIQUE_NAME(My_Lock){ mutex };
```

Using the 
**COUNTER** preprocessor symbol will generate a unique variable name that you simply don't care about.

Comment: The problem here is that at the end of the lock scope, the lock won't be released but when the scope is left that contains the LOCK(mutex) statement.