# Show Warning for "anonymous" variable creation in c++

Tags: c++, gcc

I've a class like this:

```
class ScopedLock {
public:
    ScopedLock (Locker *lock) { /*...*/ }
    ~ScopedLock () { /*...*/ }
};
```

Normally it's called like (this will call the constructor/destructor of ScopedLock at the correct place) :

```
{
    ScopedLock l(&locker);
    // ...
}
```

I've accidentally called it like:

```
{
    ScopedLock(&locker);
    // ...
}
```

What is the name for such a "thing"? Unused anonymous local variable?

Is there a possibility to prevent this? Is there a compiler warning available for such a "thing"?

Comment: You 've created an _unnamed temporary_ of type `ScopedLock` that lives briefly and then dies at the `;`.

Comment: _"Normally it's called like: ..."_ So you intended a function forward declaration there? Be aware of the _most vexing parse_!

Comment: Also I don't think there should be a warning generated, there might be cases, where such is done intentionally.

Comment: I would have expected `[[nodiscard]] ScopedLock (...) { ...}` to issue the wanted warning, but instead, I got a warning that it cannot apply the attribute to constructor :-/

Comment: Amazing video about this here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkgszkPnV8g&t=29m40s

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47602539/emulate-c-sharp-lock-statement-in-c) is also interesting in this context.

Answer (score 4):

You have created an *unnamed temporary / nameless temporary* object of type `ScopedLock` that lives briefly and then dies at the `;`. The compiler does not issue a warning as it assumes you are doing something useful with it. It does not go into a ctor body to inspect if that might be the case. For example you want to create a temporary where your constructor might do some work:

```
ScopedLock() {
    // do some work
}
```

You can't force a compiler to show a warning for such use-cases and there is no such flag in GCC.

The following SO posts can prove beneficial:

- [How to avoid C++ anonymous
  objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189742/how-to-avoid-c-anonymous-objects)
- [Prevent the creation of temporary
  objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130254/prevent-the-creation-of-temporary-objects)

Answer (score 3):

You can make a construction function marked as `nodiscard` that should be invoked instead of constructor.

```
#include <iostream>

class ScopedLock final
{
    private: ScopedLock(int, int) {std::cout << "constructed" << std::endl;}
    private: ScopedLock(void)                            = delete;
    private: ScopedLock(ScopedLock const &)              = delete;
    private: ScopedLock(ScopedLock &&)                   = delete;
    private: ScopedLock & operator =(ScopedLock const &) = delete;
    private: ScopedLock & operator =(ScopedLock &&)      = delete;

    public: [[nodiscard]] static ScopedLock
    construct(int x, int y)
    {
        return ScopedLock{x, y};   
    }
};

int main()
{
    ScopedLock(12, 123); // Error
    ScopedLock::construct(12, 123); // Warning
    auto lock(ScopedLock::construct(12, 123)); // Ok
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qSlF9ODVjlcqozsi)